# Navigation does not work in WinForms BlazorWebView

Tags: winforms, blazor, .net-7.0

The Blazor sample app is correctly rendered in the WinForms BlazorWebView but navigation does not work.

I've followed this tuto : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/tutorials/windows-forms?view=aspnetcore-7.0
Visual Studio 17.5.5 en net7.0-windows
The blazor app starts correctly: the button increments the counter.

I duplicate Counter.razor to Counter2.razor.
In Counter2.razor

- I change the h1 to Counter 2
- I add @page "/Counter2"

In Counter.razor, I add

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<p><button @onclick="@OnClick">Counter 2</button></p>
<p><a href="/Counter2">Counter 2</a></p>
```

And in the @code section, I add

```
private void OnClick()
{
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Counter2");
}
```

At run, neither the button nor the anchor navigates to Counter2.
The NavigationManager is not null.

Comment: If you want to load another Form that renders a Counter2 page, then create another Form, add a BlazorWebView, set the `.HostPage` in its Constructor and, in `OnClick()` create a new Form and show it, e.g., `private void OnClick() => new Counter2().Show();` (where `Counter2` is the name assigned to a Form)

Comment: I have no idea but here is a working sample for .net 6. https://github.com/danroth27/BlazorWinForms

Comment: @Jimi The purpose is to navigate between razor pages within the same blazorWebView, so inside the same form.

Comment: Jeb, you pointed me in the right direction. I had to add Main.razor containing the Router, Shared.MainLayout and @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing in _Imports.razor.

Comment: @PaulDurant I am facing this issue. I tried adding MainLayout.razor and Routes.razor but it didn't fix the issue.

Could you share your the sample working project. Thanks